# Regex: replace whitespaces with hyphens and allow only a-z

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with regex here.

How do I replace whitespaces with hyphens and allow only a-z symbols?

```
public String filterSpeciesName(String species) {
    return species.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
}
```

An example would be

```
input string "Bar''r$ack Put1in"
output string "barrack-putin"
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need a regex for that. Simple string replacement is usually simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return species.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "-").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z-]", "").toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace any space character by hyphens, use `String#replaceAll("\\s", "-")`.

Then, if you want to simply remove the characters that are not `a-z`, use `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z-]", "")`, assuming you don't want to get rid of your newly added hyphens :)

But I would rather recommend you to maybe just:

- **match** if `species.replaceAll("\\s", "-")` matches `^[a-zA-Z-]+$`
- **throw** an `Exception` if this is not the case
- **return** the formatted value otherwise